# How to stop loop when odd number starts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get `[11, 12, 15]` from `[4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]`
In this code, the loop should stop when an odd element starts in the list and print the rest of the list.
I wrote it but didn't get the actual values:

```
data = [4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]
emp = []
for i in data:
    if i%2 ==0:
        emp.append(i)
        while i%2 !=0:
            break
    
print([x for x in data if x not in emp])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using `itertools.dropwhile`

```
r = list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, data))
```

Result is:
`[11, 12, 15]`

This drops from your list as long the lambda returns `True`.

See [itertools.dropwhile doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) for further information

Comment: And to do the reverse, use `takewhile`! Neat!

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
data = [4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]
emp = []
found_odd = False

for i in data:
  if i % 2:           # True when i is odd
    found_odd = True  # Becomes True of first odd detected
  
  if found_odd:
    emp.append(i)     # Append if odd has been detected

print(emp)
# Output: [11, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you meant to accomplish with the while loop.

You check whether the entry is odd or even, and add it to the list if it is even.  If it is odd, you need to break.  This you do with an `else` on the `if`, like this:

```
data = [4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]
emp = []
for i in data:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        emp.append(i)
    else:
        break

print([x for x in data if x not in emp])
```

That is a small change to your program to make it work.  A simpler way, however, would be like this:

```
data = [4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]
output = []
start_copying = False
for i in data:
    if not start_copying and i % 2 == 1:
        start_copying = True
    if start_copying:
        output.append(i)
print(output)
```

This puts exactly what you want into the output list, rather than putting in what you don't want and using that to decide what to print, as the first solution does.

Or, find the index of the first element, then slice the array to get the remainder:

```
data = [4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]
output = []
index = 0
for i in data:
    if i % 2 == 1:
        break;
    index += 1
output = data[index:]
print(output)
```

Comment: Although I agree that the itertools example is excellent, perhaps the different options can be instructional.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply stop the entire loop when odd number starts, you have to break it out the moment the list encounters i%2 != 0

```
data = [4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]
emp = []
for i in data:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        emp.append(i)
    else:
        break

print([x for x in data if x not in emp])
```

Just realised there's someone with the exact same code above me.

Comment: A bunch of us were all answering at about the same time....  though the itertools answer is the best one, this one, showing the minimal change to the original code, has value for helping the OP, or someone reading the question later, understand his mistake

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using explicit looping and a similar approach as you do:

```
data = [4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]

i = 0
while not data[i] % 2:
    i += 1
new_data = [data[j] for j in range(i, len(data))]
print(new_data)
# [11, 12, 15]
```

or, using iterators:

```
iter_data = iter(data)


x = next(iter_data)
while not x % 2:
    x = next(iter_data)
new_data = [x] + [x for x in iter_data]
print(new_data)
# [11, 12, 15]
```

This only check for parity as much as strictly necessary.

---

Of course, in production code one should use `itertools.dropwhile()` as already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy for that task:

```
import numpy as np    

data = [4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]
emp = []
odd_number_indices = np.where(np.array(data) % 2 != 0)[0]
if odd_number_indices.size != 0:
    index_first_odd = odd_number_indices[0]
    emp = np.array(data)[index_first_odd:].tolist()
```

This solution might not be efficient if the `data`-list is super long.